# Cant send push in firebase .sendToDevice()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm simply trying to make a web push notifications work but I cant seem to get past the .sendToDevice() method, it runs but I dont receive any push notifications. Can someone please tell/show me what im doing wrong here...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
  console.info("Running..");
  // Only edit data when it is first created.
  if (change.before.exists()) {
    return null;
  }
  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!change.after.exists()) {
    return null;
  }
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const NOTIFICATION_KEY = context.params.notificationId
  const NOTIFICATION_DATA = change.after.val();
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: `New Message from ${NOTIFICATION_DATA.user}!`,
      body: NOTIFICATION_DATA.message,
      icon: NOTIFICATION_DATA.userProfileImg,
      click_action: `https://google.com`
    }
  };

  return admin.database().ref('/tokens').once('value').then((data) => {
    if ( !data.val( ) ) return;

      const snapshot = data.val();
      const tokens = [];

      for(let key in snapshot) {
        tokens.push( snapshot[key].token);
      }

      console.info(tokens);
      console.info(snapshot);

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  })
});
```

Comment: did you setup this also https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?

Comment: I made a simple application using the `firebase-tools` and then `firebase init`, I save the user tokens and save the notifications but I cant seem to send them to devices..

Comment: did you ever fix this issue? I think mine only works for topics but not if I try to send it via tokens to specific devices.